# Help needed for using WindowsMediaPlayerClass on Windows Mobile device - volume issue

Tags: windows-mobile, wmp

I am using WindowsMediaPlayerClass() instance to play an audio file within my application. This audio file is mono audio. Some people complained that - when they play the same audio file via windows media player - the sound is clear and loud; but when they play it using my application that uses WindowsMediaPlayerClass() instance with WindowsMediaPlayerClass.settings.volume=100. I tried tweaking WindowsMediaPlayerClass.settings.balance but it gives NotImplementedException for some reason.

```
        if (mywmp.settings.get_isAvailable("volume"))
          mywmp.settings.volume = 100;
        if (mywmp.settings.get_isAvailable("balance"))
          mywmp.settings.balance = 100;
```

Is there any way, I can boost the volume through normalization / equalization techniques in WMP ?

And the IWMPSettings interface is defined as below that contains volume and balance both but only volume works (balance fails). Dont know why ? Any pointers please ?

```
    namespace WMPLib
{
    [TypeLibType(4160)]
    [Guid("9104D1AB-80C9-4FED-ABF0-2E6417A6DF14")]
    public interface IWMPSettings
    {
        [DispId(101)]
        bool autoStart { get; set; }
        [DispId(102)]
        **int balance { get; set; }**
        [DispId(108)]
        string baseURL { get; set; }
        [DispId(109)]
        string defaultFrame { get; set; }
        [DispId(112)]
        bool enableErrorDialogs { get; set; }
        [DispId(103)]
        bool invokeURLs { get; set; }
        [DispId(104)]
        bool mute { get; set; }
        [DispId(105)]
        int playCount { get; set; }
        [DispId(106)]
        double rate { get; set; }
        [DispId(107)]
        **int volume { get; set; }**

        [DispId(113)]
        **bool get_isAvailable(string bstrItem);**
        [DispId(110)]
        bool getMode(string bstrMode);
        [DispId(111)]
        void setMode(string bstrMode, bool varfMode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your problem or if I have the right class, but it appears that the volume setting for the MediaPlayer is supposed to go from 0.0 to 1.0.  See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.volume.aspx

Comment: That isn't the right class at all. curiousone is talking about the WMP COM interop class, not WPF's MediaPlayer.